# How to Order By Column when Column isn't of the same type?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have fields in the column that look like so:

```
2/8B, 3, 3/8B, 4/8B, 2, 6, 4/9, 9, 8/9, 8, 7, 1, 5/9, 10, 3/9, 2/9, 7/9, 6/8B, 6/9, 1/9, 5, 8B, 5/8B, 4
```

I need to sort this list in a manner like:

```
1, 1/9, 2, 2/8B, 2/9, 3, 3/8B, 3/9, 4, 4/8B, 4/9, 5, 5/8B, 5/9, 6, 6/8B, 6/9, 7, 7/9, 8, 8/9, 8B, 9, 10
```

How do I Order By to create this output?

To clear up any confusion (1/2) is not a fraction. the "/" is just a separator.

Comment: It would be helpful if you supplied a larger sort example

Comment: What do you mean by "when Column isn't of the same type"? A column can only be of one type.

Comment: Sorry, here is a larger sample '10', '4', '4/9', '5', '9', '5/9'

Comment: @kyle: Please beware of raising "Error converting data type varchar to numeric" exception, when a value does not match a very specific pattern. (For example, '2/7B' or the empty string ''.) When the specification supplies a list of values that "look like", we don't usually take that to specify a complete list of all possible values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I don't get it; using the characters you've provided DOES sort in the order you requested.  Give it a shot:</strike>

```
SELECT Test
FROM (
    SELECT '38a' AS Test
    UNION
    SELECT '1'
    UNION 
    SELECT '1/2'
    UNION
    SELECT '12'
) MyData
ORDER BY Test ASC
```

**EDIT**

Now that you've given concrete examples, I see it was the `10` and `8B` that were throwing things off.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT YourCol
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(YourCol, 'B', '.99'), '/', '.'), 
    '.8.99', '.899') AS NUMERIC(18, 4))
```

This will order it as:

> 1, 1/9, 2, 2/8B, 2/9, 3, 3/8B, 3/9, 4, 4/8B, 4/9, 5, 5/8B, 5/9, 6, 6/8B, 6/9, 7, 7/9, 8, 8/9, 8B, 9, 10

It's ugly, but it works.  If you have other letters besides B, the script will have to be changed to handle that.

Comment: Sorry, using the sample '10', '4', '4/9', '5', '9', '5/9. The results are not in order.

Comment: 1, 1/9, 10, 2, 2/8B, 2/9, 3, 3/8B, 3/9, 4, 4/8B, 4/9, 5, 5/8B, 5/9, 6, 6/8B, 6/9, 7, 7/9, 8, 8/9, 8B, 9

Comment: @Kyle -- is that the order you want it sorted in?  Edit your question with better examples and a defined sort order.

Comment: This will throw an exception (cause the statement to fail) if any string value fails to match a very specific pattern. (e.g. '2/7B'). The specification appears to be a sample of data, not a complete list of every possible value.  A more general approach would insulate the statement from failing due to an unexpected value.

Answer (score 1):

This question is fraught with problems.  Essentially you are trying to write a sorting function that can look at those strings and make a human interpretation of them.  This means that eventually the naming schema will change in a way that any human understands, but your code won't and then you have a bug.

I don't know how you don't go down this road.  But defend and warn and elevate as much as you can.

Comment: +1 Excellent points about "defend and warn".  The selected answer has a SQL expression that will throw an exception (FAIL) when an unexpected value is encountered. It's much better to code defensively, verify that the data meets spec on input, rather than have a query start inexplicably begin failing in production at the most inopportune time years later.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the column that you are sorting by is a character data type (since some of the values are non-numeric characters) -- so a simple ORDER BY will work

```
select '38a' as value
 union
select '12'
 union
select '1/2'
 union
select '1'
order by value
```

Doesn't this give you the result that you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

One trick you can use is to pull out the leading integer from your string, sort by the integer value, and then by the string.

I don't know of any "simple" way to do this in SQL Server (i.e. without building a function).

One way to do this using native builtin SQL Server functions is to use the PATINDEX function to search for the starting position of "digits" and "non-digits", and then use those values to determine the length of the leading integer.  Use the SUBSTRING and CONVERT functions to extract the leading integer value.

It's not pretty:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN PATINDEX('[0-9]%', t.str ) = 1
    THEN
      CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', t.str ) > 0
        THEN CONVERT(INTEGER,SUBSTRING( t.str ,1,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', t.str )-1))
        ELSE CONVERT(INTEGER, t.str )
      END
    ELSE NULL
  END
, t.str
```

---

**NOTES:**

`t.str` is the placeholder for the expression that returns your string values.

This meets the specified requirements, for all values given in your test case.

Also, this does **not** throw an exception (i.e. cause the statement to fail) when "unexpected" values are encountered, for example, the empty string '' or strings without a leading integer.

This only deals with the "leading integer" portion of the string. Everything after that is compared as a string. (That means e.g. '6/10B' will sort before '1/8B', because '/1' < '/8'.

Any leading zeros on the leading integer value will be ignored for the integer compare, and be considered on the string compare. (That means e.g. '05/9' will sort before '5/8', because 5=5 but '0' < '5')

Any string values that don't have a leading digit will be assigned an integer value of NULL for the sort operation, so those will sort first.